# Nested generics with IDictionary and IEnumerable

Tags: c#

In a generic C# class for an internal reusable library, I'd like to pass a reference to "something that maps to a list of other things". The data types of what is passed in there are not supposed to be known by the library. Also, the way they are stored should not be known either, i.e. what is today a list that is held in memory, might later be a database table that is read from on demand.

So I thought I'd write this library class:

```
class GenericClass<T, U>
{
    public void Foo(IDictionary<T, IEnumerable<U>> bar)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This compiles, but trying to pass in concrete implementations does not:

```
class UsingClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = new GenericClass<string, string>();
        c.Foo(new Dictionary<string, List<string>>());
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following two syntax errors:

```
Filename.cs(46,13): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'GenericClass<string,string>.Foo(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>)' has some invalid arguments
Filename.cs(46,19): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>'
```

Replacing the `IEnumerable` on the declaration of `Foo()` with `List` fixes it, but that's of course not quite what I want.

Is this really not supported by C# (4.0) or am I just missing something obvious? What workaround would you suggest? (I'm sure this has been talked about before a lot, so links to great descriptions are fine, too.)

Yes, I should be able to write my own helper classes for that, but why do I have to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is really not supported. Imagine your Foo method looked like this:

```
public void Foo(IDictionary<T, IEnumerable<U>> bar)
{
    T key = GetKeyFromSomewhere();
    bar[key] = new U[10]; // Create an array
}
```

That looks okay, doesn't it? We can convert from `U[]` to `IEnumerable<U>`.

It's not so good from the caller's point of view though - suddenly we've got a `string[]` reference value in the dictionary, when all the values are meant to be `List<string>` references! Bang goes type safety.

You can rewrite the method as:

```
public void Foo<TValue>(IDictionary<T, TValue> bar)
    where TValue : IEnumerable<U>
```

That will let you get values *out* of the dictionary and convert them to `IEnumerable<U>` implicitly... but you'd only be able to put exactly the right type of value *into* the dictionary, and you can't build that just from a `U` value.

As of version 4, C# supports *generic variance* in restricted circumstances. So for example, this works in C# 4 (when targeting .NET 4) but previously wouldn't:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;
```

For a *lot* more on generic variance, see [Eric Lippert's blog series](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/default.aspx) on the topic. Be prepared for your brain to explode periodically.

Comment: Ehh, I don't know that I agree.  For the caller to actually have a problem, they'd have to make the breaking assumption that they will get back a `List<string>` from the dictionary, when the function only promised `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @siride: But the caller has passed in a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. That type is guaranteed to have values which are always assignment compatible with `List<string>`. If the method tries to put the wrong kind of value into that dictionary, that *really, really* should go bang somehow, ideally at compile time. Or don't you think that type safety within a generic collection is important? ;)

Comment: At any rate, that's exactly what I was looking for and my code compiles and works as expected now. Thanks, Jon!

Comment: @siride: I'd rather be annoyed by a compile-time restriction than an execution-time type safety issue :)